# Unable to Setup HashiCorp Vault on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, hashicorp-vault

I am trying to setup HashiCorp Vault on AWS. There is a quickstart guide to install Vault along with Consul.

https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/vault/

https://aws-quickstart.s3.amazonaws.com/quickstart-hashicorp-vault/doc/hashicorp-vault-on-the-aws-cloud.pdf

I followed all the steps of setting up Vault on AWS in a new VPC and in existing VPC but I was unable to complete the entire process successfully.

While trying to setup vault, the stack creation failed:

Parameters:

[image]

Events:

[image]

While trying to install Vault in existing VPC, it got installed but initialization failed as I have posted on this github issue: https://github.com/aws-quickstart/quickstart-hashicorp-vault/issues/42

Comment: Have you made sure that ec2 limits (base 20 without support increasing) aren't being hit during setup and that you have the permissions?

Comment: Yes, it has sufficient privileges and limits

Answer (score 0):

I received a similar error when I was running through the same quick-start. My issue was that I didn't have an SSL certificate ARN added to the cloudformation template inputs.